# dfs implementation using vector gives segfault

Tags: c++, vector, depth-first-search

I am tring to implement DFS usning stack in c++ but somehow this code gives me segfault. i checked using gdb it segfaults after first push in main. What is that i am missing?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<stack>
#define MAX_N 5001
using namespace std;

vector< vector<int> > g;
bool visited[MAX_N];

void dfs(int start){
    stack<int> s;
    s.push(start);
    while(!s.empty()){
        int current = s.top();
        s.pop();
        visited[current] = true;
        cout<<current<<"\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < g[current].size() ; ++i){
            if(!visited[g[current][i]]){
                s.push(g[current][i]);
                visited[g[current][i]] = true;
            }
         }
    }
}

int main() {
    g[0].push_back(1);
    g[0].push_back(2);
    g[2].push_back(3);
    g[3].push_back(4);
    dfs(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Where do you set `g`'s size to something other than zero?

Comment: assign size to g using resize() function of vector.

Comment: @Dutow i searched i cant find out . first i declared g as a vector of vectors so that it can be used as adjacency list then i am pushing elemets to it

Comment: @vidhugangwar why is that required ? isn't vector supposed to resize itself when adding new elements

Comment: vector resize automatically when you push at least one element but initially there is nothing in g

Comment: @vidhugangwar when i do  this in  main g[0].push_back(1); it pushes the first element in the vector am i wrong?

Comment: @anekix it pushes a new element into the vector that is the first element of `g`. But `g` had no elements, so "first element of `g`" is out of bounds.

Comment: @user2079303 it's confusing . i will trny to explain what is confusing to me . when we are using jsut a vector suppose vector<int> v;  then we can do v.push_back() here also only the vector was "defined only" similarlily it should extend to a 2d vector when i refrenc g[0]--> it was already defined as a vector so push_back() should work???

Comment: @user2079303 g[0] is a vector and i am pushing an element onto it which should work as expected i didint find anywhere that says to push onto a vector it should have an element the only requirement is it hsould be ddefined as a bvectro before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a `std::vector g`.

It has 0 elements.

You are trying to access its 1st element (`g[0]`).

There is no such element.

See cppreference: [std::vector::operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)